# My phone won't turn on/charge and I need to get data off of it

Tags: backup, recovery-mode, data-recovery, downloading, ram

My phone is about 5 months old and for some reason it completely stopped working the other day. When I plug it in, in order to charge nothing happens, and when I plug it into the computer no information comes up. I bought the phone from Amazon and they're letting me return it for a full refund and I just got a brand new samsung. I'm positive that I was backing up my phone the whole time I had it, but almost nothing has been retrieved when I tried to restore my old info on my new phone. Do any of you guys know anyway to get the data off my Samsung's memory without being able to use the screen or it registering when it's plugged into my laptop? If I need to go to the Samsung store and I can't handle this myself, please let me know, otherwise please give me an any info you can think of.

Also, the phone was set to backup, and absolutely nothing backed up the whole entire time. i am so confused and would just really appreciate some help.

Best,
Sara

Comment: Is there a led light at the front of the device? If there is a led light, what happens if you charge the device? Is it lighting up?

Comment: Then I don't think we are able to help you. I suspect that it is a hardware issue. If haven't modified the device (recovery, root, ROM) and you still have warranty on it. Try bringing it to the Samsung store and let them look at it.

Comment: yea i haven't modified the device in anyway. the phone wasn't made in the country i am currently in, so when i brought it into the store yesterday they said they couldn't fix it for me. would that mean that they also couldnt try and get anything off of it?

Comment: Oh that's a bummer, you can try to contact the Samsung support line and see if they can fix it by sending the device to them. Their support information is different by country so I can't really link you to a page.